# In minted package the formatcom option ocure bottom marging

Tags: margins, minted, code, rendering

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}


\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black,formatcom=\color{white}]{bash}
#! /bin/bash
# script to turn the screen blue
setterm -background blue
echo It is a blue day
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I get this rendering:

[image: console rendering with formatcom option]

As you see, the `formatcom` option make an additional blank line in the bottom of the source code.

So, how to delete it?

Answer (score 3):

Minted uses fancyvrb under the hood. To change the text color with the `formatcom` option you have to define a function that redefines `\FancyVerbFormatLine` as in

```
\newcommand{\shellfgcolor}{%
  \def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\textcolor{white}{##1}}%
}
```

and pass it to the `formatcom` option of minted as in `formatcom=\shellfgcolor`

So your MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\shellfgcolor}{%
  \def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{\textcolor{white}{##1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black,formatcom=\shellfgcolor]{bash}
#! /bin/bash
# script to turn the screen blue
setterm -background blue
echo It is a blue day
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

that renders as[image]